# Angular/Jasmine - Test HTML element inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test the existence of an `input` that is inside an `ng-if`, without the `ng-if` the test passes perfectly but not with the `ng-if` which is normal since `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM.

Here is the `ng-if`

```
<div ng-ig="$ctrl.model.joineryTypes">
  <input type="" name="">
</div>
```

The test

```
import angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

let scope
let rootScope
let compile
let htmlElement
let ctrl

fdescribe('roomsCommonForm', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('roomsCommonModule')
  })

  beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_
    compile = _$compile_
    scope = rootScope.$new()
    htmlElement = compile(`<rooms-common-form></rooms-common-form>`)(scope)
    rootScope.$digest()
  }))

  beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
    let bindings = {
      model: {}
    }
    ctrl = $componentController('roomsCommonForm', null, bindings)
  }))

  it('should contain one input', () => {
    const inputItem = htmlElement.get(0).querySelectorAll('input')
    expect(inputItem.length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

How I can simulate that object `$ctrl.model.joineryTypes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your test slightly; first alter the original binding to include the joineryTypes:

```
let bindings = {
  model: {
    joineryTypes: false
  }
};
```

So now it's false, you'd just need to alter it in another test:

```
it('should look inside the ng-if', () => {
  ctrl.model.joineryTypes = true;
});
```

Then you should be able to reach inside the ng-if block.